# Find $a$ given some additional conditions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The problem is:

> If $x+y+z=3$ and $xy+xz+yz=a$, where $a$ is a real number, find $a$ if the difference between the maximum and minimum value of $x$ is $8$.

So what I did was use Vieta's equations to get the cubic

$$k^3-3k^2+ak+c$$

where the solutions $k$ of this cubic is equal to $x$, $y$, and $z$. I took the derivative of this, and took it to be zero (to find the minimum and maximum value) and got
$$3k^2-6k+a=0$$
The rest of the problem is easy from there, since solving it gives me two solutions in terms of $a$. If I then subtract the solutions and equate it to $8$, I can get the answer.

What I ask is if my reasoning for the first part is correct. That is to say, did I use Vieta's formulas right? Am I missing anything?

Comment: Nothing? Not even a comment if this is right or not? I just need one word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! I was wrong! I can't believe it took me this long to realize it, though.

If I have the cubic in $k$:

$$k^3-3k^2+ak+c=0$$

and I want to find the maximum and minimum values of the roots, it would be pointless to find the maximum and minimum values of the *function* (as I had done in my "solution")! That would make my work later also pointless.

Well, it looks like it's back to the drawing board for me. Thankfully, my teacher is giving us a solution today.

Thanks anyways guys!